# Why do "strings", i.e. character arrays, have a null-terminating element, whereas integer arrays don't?

Tags: c++, c

From what I understand, character arrays in C/C++ have a null-terminating character for the purpose of denoting an off-the-end element of that array, while integer arrays don't; they have some internal mechanism that is hidden from the user, but they obviously know their own size since the user can do `sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(int)` (Is that technically a hack?). Wouldn't it make sense for an integer array to have some null-terminating `int` -- call it `i` or something?

Why is this? It has never made any sense to me.

Comment: Because they don't have a fixed size.

Comment: No it wouldn't make sense at all. Assuming null is zero, if you added a null terminator to an integer array how would you distinguish the null value from a zero value? Using any value would prevent it from being used in the array and there is only a finite number of values that fit in an integral type. Also `sizeof` is a compile time construct and not a hack.

Comment: A character array more closely resembles an integer array.  A C-Style string is a sequence of characters terminated by '\0'.  It can be *treated* as an array since the sequence can be indexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, in C, strings are *not* the same as character arrays, they exist at a level *above* arrays in much the same way as a linked list exists at a level above structures.

This is an example  of a string:

```
"pax is great"
```

This is an example of a character array:

```
{ 'p', 'a', 'x' }
```

This is an example of a character array that just happens to be equivalent to a string:

```
{ 'p', 'a', 'x', '\0' }
```

In other words, C string are built on *top* of character arrays.

If you look at it another way, neither integer arrays nor "real" character arrays (like `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` for example) have a terminating character.

You can quite easily do the same thing (have a terminator) with an integer array of people's ages, using `-1` (or any negative number) as the terminator.

The only difference is that you'll write your *own* code to handle it rather than using code helpfully provided in the C standard library, things like:

```
size_t agelen (int *ages) {
    size_t len = 0;
    while (*ages++ >= 0)
        len++;
    return len;
}

int *agecpy (int *src, int *dst) {
    int *d = dst;
    while (*s >= 0)
        *d++ = *src++;
    *dst = -1;
    return dst;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `string` does not exists in `c`.

Because the `null terminator` is there to mark the end of the `input` and it doesn't have to be the length of the given array.

Answer (score 0):

This is by convention, treating null as a non-character. Unlike other major system software languages of then e.g. PL/1 which had a leading integer to denote the length of a variable length character string, C was designed to treat strings as simply character arrays and did not want the overhead and in particular any portability issues (such as sizeof int) nor any limitations (what about very long strings). The convention has stuck because it worked out rather well.

To denote end of an int array as you have suggested would require a non-Int marker. That could be rather difficult to arrange. And sizeof an int array as you are figuring out is merely taking advantage of your knowledge of *alloc - there is absolutely nothing in C to prevent you from cobbling together an "array" by clever management of allocated memory. Modern compilers of course contain many convenience checks on wayward code and someone with better knowledge of compilers could clarify/rectify my comments here. C++ Vector contains an explicit knowledge of array capacity, for example.

A lot of places you can see a different Field Separator FS character used to separate out strings. E.g., CSV. But if you were to do that, you will need to write you own std libraries - thousands and thousands of lines of good, tested code.

Answer (score 0):

A C-Style string is a **collection of characters** terminated by '\0'.  It is *not* an array.

The collection can be indexed like an array.

Because the length of the collection can vary, the length must be determined by counting the number of characters in the collection.

A convenient *representation* is an array because an array is also a collection.

One difference is that an array is a fixed sized data structure.  The collection of characters may not be a fixed size; for example, it can be concatenated.

Comment: Sure is a C-"string" a `char`-array. At least those C-"strings" handled by the `str*()`-family of functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about the problem of how to represent strings, you have two choices: 1) store a count of letters followed by the letters or 2) store the letters followed by some unique special character used as an end of string marker.

End of string marker is more flexible - longer strings possible, easier to use, etc.

BTW you can have terminator on an int array if you want... Nothing stopping you saying that a -1 for example means the end if the list, as long as you are sure that the -1 is unique.